# Memcache installation on easyapache 4

Tags: memcached, whm

I just installed WHM v58 (latest version) with easyapache 4 and when i try to install memcache via software => Module Installers => PHP Pecl i've got a problem.

When i launch memcached (2.2.0) - PHP extension for interfacing with memcached via libmemcached library - i've got an error while checking sasl. 
I need to run installation with the option "--disable-memcached-sasl" but i don't know how to do it in WHM ?

```
checking for sasl/sasl.h... no
configure: error: no, sasl.h is not available. Run configure with --disable-    memcached-sasl to disable this check
ERROR: `/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/memcached/configure --    with-php-config=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php-config --with-libmemcached-    dir=no' failed
```

Can you help me ?

Thks

Answer (score 0):

You should install cyrus-sasl libraries and development headers. The configure script is looking for a file as you can see in the error message (sasl.h).

You can install them by issuing this command from a ssh shell (as root) or with sudo:

```
yum -y install cyrus-sasl-lib cyrus-sasl-devel
```

After the install try re-installing that memcached. You also need the memcached daemon installed in order to use that (in case you haven't installed it already).